# Agregar votos estilo reddit/hacker news en Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Me gustaría agregar algo similar al sistema de votaciones que tienen muchas páginas web como StackOverflow, Reddit, Hacker News, etc. Quería crear un botón para que hiciera esta tarea en el template principal que tengo, tratando de crear un `FormView` pero me doy cuenta que tal vez no funcione, porque estoy usando un `ModelForm` que no tiene el campo `vote` que tiene el modelo porque lo agarra por defecto.

template

```
{% for new in News %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
       <form action="{% url 'New:vote' %} new.id" method="POST">
           <input type="submit" value="upvote">
           {{ new.vote }}
       </form>
        <a href="{{ new.url }}">{{ new.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

trate con esta vista

```
class NewVote(FormView):
    form_class = 'NewForm'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('New:list', args=(self.object.id, ))
```

y tengo estas url, actualmente  en list, que es la pagina principal me esta dando un error

> Reverse for 'vote' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vote/(?P\d+)/$']

```
url(r'^$', NewList.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^add/', NewAdd.as_view(), name='add'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewEdit.as_view(), name='edit'),
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^vote/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewVote.as_view(), name='vote'),
```

Y este es mi formulario donde tenia pensado agregar el campo para el boton, pero sinceramente no se si sea lo correcto para hacerlo

```
class NewForm(ModelForm):

    error_message = {
        'url_exists': 'The url alredy exists'
    }

    class Meta:
        model = New
        fields = ('title', 'url')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data)

    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url'] 
        if New.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('The URL alredy exists')
        return url
```

Tal vez pueda crear un nuevo form, pero seria apartir de un ModelForm o puedo acceder a él de otra forma?

Es algo largo el post, pero espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preguntar por el tema del voto, y como hacerlo, es suficiente para que den por cerrada tu pregunta, porque está basada inicialmente en opiniones, y además es un tema demasiado amplio, ahora, para solucionar el único problema que veo de código que tienes es lo siguiente:

Tienes esta línea:

```
<form action="{{% url 'New:vote' %} new.id" method="POST">
```

La cual, de entrada tienes un `{` de mas luego del `action="` y debes de saber que los argumentos a las urls desde el tag `{% url ... %}` van dentro del tag, por lo que esa línea, deberia quedar así:

```
<form action="{% url 'New:vote' new.id %}" method="POST">
```

Espero haberte ayudado con tu pregunta, solo puedo solucionar ese error porque ayudarte con lo otro es hacer todo un backend para hacer un sistema de votación.

Comment: Deberia tratar entonces en hacer el sistema de votaciones y volver cuando tenga un problema con el tema? Gracias por ayudarme con este problema, soy un tonto :c

Comment: Si, lo mejor es poner problemas específicos, y no eres un tonto, son errores por los que todos pasamos

Comment: Si, lo sé errores que pasan. Gracias por la ayuda. Volveré con alguna otra pregunta!

Comment: Sigue dandome el mismo error, incluso al quitar la llave que me indicaste

Comment: Edita la pregunta, con lo que actualmente tienes de código, para poder ayudarte más

Comment: Es el mismo codigo, lo unico que quite fue la llave que me dijiste

Comment: Pero no tienes que quitarla sin más, debes ponerla dentro del tag

Comment: Ya logre arreglarlo! Ahora sigo sufriendo para hacer el sistema de votacion :c

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como respondida para cerrar esta pregunta